# JNDI injection of app name doesn't work, lookup does

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

This doesn't seem to work (=null):

```
@Resource(name = "java:app/AppName")
private String appName;
```

But a lookup of the same name does:

```
appName = (String) new javax.naming.InitialContext().lookup("java:app/AppName");
```

I found many examples having a *lookup* property in `@Resource` instead of *name*. However, I can't find anything about that, I'm quite confident it should be *name*, the *former* isn't part of the spec.

FYI, I'm using Glassfish 3.1 and I'm accessing appName from a `@PostConstruct` method in a singleton bean.

Comment: Anyone wanting to share why they put -1, or is it purely arbitrary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of "`lookup`" instead of "`name`" in this case is correct, as the entry is already defined in the `java:app` namespace and is merely being looked up, rather than defined. This is part of the [Java EE 6 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316) (which [Glassfish 3.1](http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1-final.html) implements): [`@Resource#lookup()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html#lookup()).

Alternative to looking up the app name using `InitialContext`, you can also use the `@Resource` annotation using the `lookup` attribute:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:app/AppName")
private String appName;
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense and the documentation seems to say just that. However, it seems that my javax.annotation.Resource was the one from jdk 6, which goes on pair with Java EE 5. I switched to JDK7 and it now works!